# Conflic between calendars

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime

I have two dates pickers like this:

[image]

**Html:**

```
      <asp:TextBox ID="fecha_ini" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar2" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="DateChange" DayNameFormat="FirstLetter" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="11px" NextMonthText="." PrevMonthText="." SelectMonthText="»" SelectWeekText="›" CssClass="myCalendar" CellPadding="0">
            <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#b0b0b0" />
            <DayStyle CssClass="myCalendarDay" ForeColor="#2d3338" />
            <DayHeaderStyle CssClass="myCalendarDayHeader" ForeColor="#2d3338" />
            <SelectedDayStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="12px" CssClass="myCalendarSelector" />
            <TodayDayStyle CssClass="myCalendarToday" />
            <SelectorStyle CssClass="myCalendarSelector" />
            <NextPrevStyle CssClass="myCalendarNextPrev" />
            <TitleStyle CssClass="myCalendarTitle" />
        </asp:Calendar>
    </td>
 <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="fecha_fin" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="DateChange" DayNameFormat="FirstLetter" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="11px" NextMonthText="." PrevMonthText="." SelectMonthText="»" SelectWeekText="›" CssClass="myCalendar" CellPadding="0">
                    <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#b0b0b0" />
                    <DayStyle CssClass="myCalendarDay" ForeColor="#2d3338" />
                    <DayHeaderStyle CssClass="myCalendarDayHeader" ForeColor="#2d3338" />
                    <SelectedDayStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="12px" CssClass="myCalendarSelector" />
                    <TodayDayStyle CssClass="myCalendarToday" />
                    <SelectorStyle CssClass="myCalendarSelector" />
                    <NextPrevStyle CssClass="myCalendarNextPrev" />
                    <TitleStyle CssClass="myCalendarTitle" />
                </asp:Calendar>

            </td>
```

**.CS controller**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
 fecha_ini.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
 fecha_fin.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es-MX");
     }

 protected void DateChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fecha_fin.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            fecha_ini.Text = Calendar2.SelectedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

        }
```

Problem is when I pick date in second calendar, it changes it correctly but refresh first calendar date back to Today, how can I solve that? Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the initial setting of the TextBoxes inside an `IsPostBack` check. If not they will be reset every time there is a Postback.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es-MX");

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        fecha_ini.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        fecha_fin.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your page load event is being triggered when the page posts back. Try wrapping your statement in an if statement so that it only executes when the page loads.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
   {
      fecha_ini.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
      fecha_fin.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
      Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es-MX");
    }
```